# Atmospheric scattering and fog

Tags: sky, volumetric-light, fog, atmospheric-scattering

I've implemented a dynamic sky model (Preetham). I've got Rayleigh and Mie scattering working fine, but I'm not sure how to get the foggy effects in [this Unity article](http://blogs.unity3d.com/2015/05/28/atmospheric-scattering-in-the-blacksmith/)

Here is what I have so far:
[image: dynamic sky]

How do I get the fog/haze in my scene ? Is it a matter of adding the same scattering shader to each mesh in my scene ?
I tried adding a fog shader to my meshes but the fog colour will obviously not match the sky colour.
I've also tried adding volumetric light scattering as a post-process from this [GPU gems](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch13.html) but I can't come close to getting the result I'm looking for.

In both cases I end up having my meshes be a distinct colour along the horizon, they do not fade out into the horizon nor do they have all the nice haze above them.